# Python access the Login directly without using With Function as Key :

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, authentication, with-statement

Here is the complete code where i am trying to use ForexConnect().get_history(....  instead of  fx.get_history(  and i do not want this line of code "with ForexConnect() as fx:" how to achieve this ,the last section of code given produces  excpetion issues .

Why i do not want to use "with ForexConnect() as fx:" The reason is once the session "with ForexConnect() as fx:" the function is logged out .My idea is to be in the session after once logged in .So i do not want to try this with "with ForexConnect() as fx:"

```
import argparse

import pandas as pd
from forexconnect import ForexConnect, fxcorepy

import common_samples

parser = False


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process command parameters.')
    common_samples.add_main_arguments(parser)
    common_samples.add_instrument_timeframe_arguments(parser)
    common_samples.add_date_arguments(parser)
    common_samples.add_max_bars_arguments(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    if parser == False :
        #args = parse_args()
        str_user_id = 'Dxxxx'
        str_password = 'xxxxx'
        str_url = "http://www.fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp"
        str_connection = 'Demo'
        str_session_id = 'None'
        str_pin = 'None'
        str_instrument = 'USOil'
        str_timeframe = 'W1'
        quotes_count = 5
        date_from = None
        date_to = None
    else :
        args = parse_args()
        str_user_id = args.l
        str_password = args.p
        str_url = args.u
        str_connection = args.c
        str_session_id = args.session
        str_pin = args.pin
        str_instrument = args.i
        str_timeframe = args.timeframe
        quotes_count = args.quotescount
        date_from = args.datefrom
        date_to = args.dateto

    with ForexConnect() as fx:
        try:
            fx.login(str_user_id, str_password, str_url,
                     str_connection, str_session_id, str_pin,
                     common_samples.session_status_changed)

            print("")
            print("Requesting a price history...")
            print(str_instrument,str_timeframe,date_from,date_to,quotes_count)
            history = fx.get_history(str_instrument, str_timeframe, date_from, date_to, quotes_count)
            current_unit, _ = ForexConnect.parse_timeframe(str_timeframe)

            date_format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
            print("print history ",history)
            df = pd.DataFrame(history, columns=['Date', 'BidOpen', 'BidHigh','BidLow', 'BidClose', 'AskOpen', 'AskHigh', 'AskLow', 'AskClose', 'Volume'])
            print(df)
            if current_unit == fxcorepy.O2GTimeFrameUnit.TICK:
                print("Date, Bid, Ask")
                print(history.dtype.names)
                for row in history:
                    print("{0:s}, {1:,.5f}, {2:,.5f}".format(
                        pd.to_datetime(str(row['Date'])).strftime(date_format), row['Bid'], row['Ask']))
            else:
                print("Date, BidOpen, BidHigh, BidLow, BidClose, Volume")
                for row in history:
                    print("{0:s}, {1:,.5f}, {2:,.5f}, {3:,.5f}, {4:,.5f}, {5:d}".format(
                        pd.to_datetime(str(row['Date'])).strftime(date_format), row['BidOpen'], row['BidHigh'],
                        row['BidLow'], row['BidClose'], row['Volume']))
        except Exception as e:
            common_samples.print_exception(e)
        try:
            fx.logout()
        except Exception as e:
            common_samples.print_exception(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("")
    input("Done! Press enter key to exit\n")
```

Here i want to login once and be in the logged in session forever.
With the below function this is working fine .But here the problem is once the With section is over the session is disconnected.

```
with ForexConnect() as fx:
    try:
        fx.login(str_user_id, str_password, str_url,
                 str_connection, str_session_id, str_pin,
                 common_samples.session_status_changed)
        history = fx.get_history(str_instrument, str_timeframe, date_from, date_to, quotes_count)
            current_unit, _ = ForexConnect.parse_timeframe(str_timeframe)
```

To stay in the session tried the below code without using the "With" and as :

Here the login is successful but could not get the data in history = ForexConnect().get_history

Error Code :

```
                ForexConnect().login(str_user_id, str_password, str_url,
                    str_connection, str_session_id, str_pin,
                    common_samples.session_status_changed)
               **history = ForexConnect().get_history(str_instrument, str_timeframe, date_from, date_to, quotes_count)**
```

How to make it the ** ** code work without any exception error without using With --- as : keyworkds.
what is the alternative for this with and as :  why when i try to access as history = ForexConnect().get_history ( ... it is giving error how to overcome this issue.

Comment: I can't really understand anything you wrote after the words "Error Code". Can you try and rephrase the question please? Or can someone who understands please edit this?

Comment: It is very simple without using this line "with ForexConnect() as fx:" how i can perform this operation  history = fx.get_history this line of code works fine but when i try history = ForexConnect().get_history(str_instrument it fails why ?